# How to add horizontal scroll on vertical recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So i have a recyclerview like this :

[image]

as you can see, the screen width is not enough for displaying all the text nicely, so i need to add horizontal scroll so user can scroll horizontally and vertically at the same time, how do i do this?

Comment: for better answer please share your code

Comment: post your list item xml.

Comment: the view is created programatically, so the xml only have linearlayout as a parent.

Comment: i think  you only need to add your recycler view row inflated layout in Horizontal scrollview then it working perfect try it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HorizontalScrollView with LinearLayout as child. Set it's Orientation to horizontal and add your dynamic views to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_main"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            // Add your dynamic views to this layout.
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this layout manager to allow horizontal scrolling of long items in a vertical LinearLayoutManager.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


public class FullScrollLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    private int offset;
    private int maxOffset;

    public FullScrollLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayoutCompleted(RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.onLayoutCompleted(state);
        updateLayout();
    }

    private void updateLayout() {
        int n = getChildCount();
        maxOffset = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
            View view = getChildAt(i);
            updateMaxOffset(view);
        }
        if(offset>maxOffset) offset = maxOffset;
        offsetChildren();
    }

    private void updateMaxOffset(View view) {
        int x = view.getRight();
        int ownWidth = getWidth();
        if(x>ownWidth) maxOffset = Math.max(maxOffset,x-ownWidth);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        if(dx<0) {
            if(-dx>offset) dx = -offset;
        }
        else
        if(dx>0) {
            if(dx+offset>maxOffset) dx = maxOffset-offset;
        }
        offset += dx;
        offsetChildren();
        return dx;
    }

    private void offsetChildren() {
        int n = getChildCount();
        for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
            View view = getChildAt(i);
            view.setTranslationX(-offset);
        }
    }

    public int getOffset() {
        return offset;
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index) {
        super.addView(child, index);
        child.setTranslationX(-offset);
        child.post(()->updateMaxOffset(child));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried it, works like a charm 

Comment: Small issue, this does not change the maxOffset when you scroll so it does not enable horizontal scroll for items that came after some scroll. Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: I edited the answer to fix the problem. It is done by overriding addView() method. I also recommend executing RecyclerView.setItemAnimator(null) to remove the default animator, because it uses the view translation for its own purposes and breaks the horizontal scroll.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. What I did to fix it was to override onScrollStateChanged, and calculate maxOffset in it. Is that also a correct way of doing it ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your row layout :

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     //Your layout item here

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: doen't work, the entire recycler view wont show up if i use that.

Answer (score 1):

Put vertical `RecyclerView` inside `HorizontalScrollView` like below.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/tasks_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Also the root element of the item view for the `RecyclerView` has to have width `wrap_content` not `match_parent`, by setting it's width to `wrap_content` it allows it to expand the width of its parent which in this case would be the `RecyclerView`.

Now in the item view either give `wrap_content` or fixed widths to the inner views which in your case are the views to display "No", "Wonum", "Item num", "Quantity" and "UOM". By giving inner views fixed or `wrap_content` option they will expand automatically or according to the given width hence expanding their parent.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add android:scrollHorizontally="true" in your TextView
2. If there are more than one view in your list item, you can use HorizontalScrollView

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
                linearLayoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL
                selected_recycler_view.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

adapter = TAdapter(this, existing.selectedArrayList)
```